# Brew Python3.7 install on Mac High OSierra 10.13.6. Help understand openssl install instructions

Tags: python, macos, ssl, openssl, homebrew

I am having problems installing python and keep getting openssl errors. So I have reinstalled numerous times and still struggling. I think I am not following the below instructions properly and hope someone can explain what I should do. I have read everything on openssl errors online over the last 3 weeks and am practically at the end of my wits. I will very likely give up learning to program if I can't figure this out.

I am able to install packages using pip3. But get errors if I need to access web pages. Examples of errors I get:

pip3 installed geopy but running below raises a huge error the final part of which I have included below:

```
import geopy
geocoder=geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3(domain="maps.google.co.uk")
geocoder.geocode('Cambridge', exactly_one=False)
```

> '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'

I can install pandas and pandas_datareader but running below raises error the final part of which follows the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 511, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /quote/TSLA/history?period1=946699200&period2=1483243199&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))

So I need to know exactly what steps to take after installing python 3.7 via brew as stated below.

1. Do I need to add additional certificates and as a result place a .pem file in certs directory? When and why is such an action necessary?
2. Do I only need to run c_rehash if the answer to question 1 is true?
3. Do I need to have openssl first in my path?
4. Do I need compilers to find openssl? Under what circumstances should I set the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS as stated?
5. Do I need pkg-config to find openssl?

Basically, I am a beginner python user and not sure how many of these things are necessary for me if I just want to install packages using pip3 and be able to securely access data and websites online.

> $ brew install openssl
>   Updating Homebrew...
>   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2p.high_sierra.
>   Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f3b0a441f330cc1e6072080557f91b61256c8b0734e8348563d0efcb2af248ce--openssl-1.0.2p.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
>   ==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2p.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
>   ==> Caveats
>   A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
>   keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
>   the System keychain), place .pem files in
>     /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
>
> and run
>     /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
>
> openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.
>
> If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:
>     echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
>     export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
>     export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
>
> For pkg-config to find openssl you may need to set:
>     export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
>
> ==> Summary
>     /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p: 1,793 files, 12.3MB

Comment: This is a brew issue, not a python issue. Wipe your brew install and try these steps perhaps https://comeroutewithme.com/2016/03/13/python-osx-openssl-issue/

Comment: following the instructions from your suggestion, here is some info. The openssl version AND ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION in python give the same result - OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018. I take it this is not an issue since python is compited against the latest version. Secondly, if I try brew link openssl, I get the following: "Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl."

Comment: i suggest you use Anaconda and python 3.6.5. Load the anaconda package manager and python from https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos   Anaconda makes it easy to load packages and other tasks required by python. The instructions are very helpful.

Comment: @jmh I tried installing via conda, python.org and brew. Each one has the same issue. Always openssl error even after following all the instructions in each conda and python.org install

Comment: oh. I'll look into that.  Sorry .